# Multiple Objective-C objects for iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, ibaction

I'm sure this is going to sound very weird, but I'll ask anyway. I have made multiple working applications for the iPhone, but I have to add everything to the original view controller. If I don't do so, the app crashes. Here is my example:

In the view controller:

```
- (IBAction) someAction: (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"lajkrbgl");

}
```

This works just fine. But, if I do the "Add File" and I choose "Objective-C Class", and put the same code in, the app just crashes whenever I press the button. How can I add more objects and have them function like they do for OS X?

EDIT: Below are the steps I took to make the new object. These steps worked for me when making an OS X application.

1. I right clicked on the "Classes" folder in Xcode.
2. I selected "Add > New File".
3. I selected "Objective-C Class" and "NSObject".
4. I made an action, "- (IBAction) someAction: (id) sender;"
5. In Interface Builder, I connected the action to a UIButton, and used "Touch Up Inside".
6. I clicked the "Build and Run" button.

After that, I clicked the button, and the application quit (almost as if i clicked the Home button). I did not get any errors. I then decided that it was because I didn't put the code in for the action, so I did that next.

```
- (IBAction) someAction: (id) sender; {
    NSLog(@"lajkrbl");
}
```

Even after this, it crashed in the exact same way, and without an error message. Can anybody see what I did wrong?

EDIT2: I just got Xcode 4 running, and when I clicked the button, it told me that this code is giving me the problem (I put "**" before the line that had the green line).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    **int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
```

}

How in the world did *that* go wrong? That is created by Xcode when I make projects!

Comment: I think the problem is with the conneciton of the ibaction. Did you connect it correct?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I did. I have tried this multiple times per week for the last couple of months.

Comment: Did you also add the new class to the IB File? You have to add the new class as a object.

Comment: Yes, I did. I have already told you that everything seems to be correctly setup. Do you have to do it differently than in OS X?

Comment: If everything was correctly set up you wouldn't be having a problem. I think Sandro is trying to help. Maybe if you post your code it will be easier to figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: I _did_ post my code. I put that code into two different objects, and I connected them to different buttons.

Comment: There's not really enough information here to diagnose the problem.  Is this the _exact_ code that seems to be causing the crash? What error do you see when the crash occurs? What does the stack look like? What's the superclass of the class to which you are trying to add this method? Please edit your question to add detail.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to get do that in the morning, so moderators, please don't lock or close this until then.

Comment: Good writeup. One step which you omitted in your edit (though you seem to have addressed it in a comment, so not a huge deal): how did you instantiate the object to which you connected the button in IB?

Comment: I simply dragged a new object out, I set the "class" to my class. After that, I right clicked on my object, and dragged the little dot next to my action's name onto the button. You want me to post pictures so you can see?

Comment: No, should be fine. Your steps are quite clearly written.

Comment: You should be able to make Xcode 4 stop on the real problem line by adding an exception breakpoint. (Xcode 4 doesn't stop on exceptions by default.) It might stop inside UIKit or something, but it sounds like any information you can get would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed different in iOS. This note in the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW38):

> Whenever you add objects to the top-level of your nib file, you should always connect those objects to outlets somewhere else in the nib file. [...] because top-level objects are retained and then autoreleased, if you did not retain the object, it might possibly be released before you had a chance to use it.

and, more definitively, [Table 1-1](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6) in the Resource Programming Guide:

> Objects in the nib file are created with a retain count of 1 and then autoreleased. [...] If you define outlets for nib-file objects, you should always define a setter method (or declared property) for accessing that outlet. Setter methods for outlets should retain their values, and setter methods for outlets containing top-level objects must retain their values to prevent them from being deallocated.

both indicate that you should add an `IBOutlet` for the object which implements the button's action method to your view controller, and have the view controller retain that object (a property makes this easy):

```
@interface ButtonCrashViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet ButtonActioner * myButtonActioner;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet ButtonActioner *myButtonActioner;

@end
```

In ButtonActioner.m:

```
- (IBAction)someAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"This didn't crash!");
}
```

You then hook the view controller's outlet and the button's action up as usual in Interface Builder.

Comment: What about IBActions? My question was about those.

Comment: @Justin: The crash isn't caused by the action; it's caused by the fact that the object has already been released before you try to perform the action.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. Give me just a few minutes to try it, and I'll tell you if it works out.

Comment: Ok. I put that exact code in, and now it won't do anything. It highlights the button, then freezes. When I hit the home button, it will quit, but I cannot get it to load again after that.

Comment: @Justin: Did you remember to `@synthesize` the outlet?

Comment: Yes I did. Should I post the code to make sure it isn't a stupid mistake on my part?

Comment: @Justin: I'd suggest, if you haven't already, creating a fresh project and just doing these few steps. That will allow you to be sure that there is no stray code or connections floating around from previous attempts. Once you understand what's happening, then integrate this into your real project.

Answer (score 2):

If you're connecting an IBAction to a method in some discrete object, that object needs to exist when the action is called. Make sure that your object that contains the IBAction code has been instantiated and is retained by whatever entity (likely a viewcontroller) contains the button.

This will probably result in that entity retaining an instance variable of type MyObject, where MyObject is your NSObject subclass containing the IBAction code.

Code example:

MyObject.m contains:

```
- (IBAction) someAction: (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"lajkrbgl");
}
```

MyViewController.xib contains a UIButton whose TouchUpInside is linked to someAction.

MyViewController.h contains:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    MyObject *myObject_;
}
```

MyViewController.m contains (in `initWithNibName:bundle:`):

```
myObject_ = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

You could optionally make myObject a property to make this all way prettier, but that's your call.

Comment: The `MyObject` instance created in this way has no relationship to the `MyObject` instance in the xib, and isn't connected to the button.

Comment: Ah, right. Answered without thinking. Personally I try and avoid IBActions; you could accomplish the same thing with the above code and setting the target and selector of the UIButton by putting the button in an outlet and setting in on viewDidLoad.

Comment: That is a good idea, kevboh. I think I'll just try to connect the actions in the viewDidLoad, like you said. This doesn't answer my question, but it does solve my problem. I would like to wait and see if someone can answer the question, however.